PHP Trait and Abstract Class Visibility Rules for Methods and Properties
I am trying to understand the visibility rules for methods and properties in PHP when using traits and classes. I noticed some behaviors that I would like to clarify:
1. Classes:

I defined a public method and property in an abstract class and tried to override them in a child class. I got an error when trying to change the visibility from public to private for the method, which stated that I cannot change public to private. However, changing from private to public was allowed for the method.
The same behavior was observed for properties. Changing the visibility from public to private for a property in a child class resulted in an error, but changing from private to public was allowed.

2. Traits:

When using traits, I know that you can change the visibility of methods using the as keyword. However, when overriding methods directly in the class using the trait, I was able to change the visibility from public to private and vice versa.
For properties defined in the trait, I was not able to change the visibility when overriding them in the class. Attempting to change a public property to private in the class using the trait resulted in an error.

I am aware of the Less Restrictive Visibility rule, but I am trying to understand why these differences exist between abstract classes and traits in PHP. Specifically:

Why can methods have their visibility changed in traits but not in classes when overriding?
Why can properties not have their visibility changed in traits while methods can?

abstract class AbstractClass {
    public function publicMethod() {}
    private function privateMethod() {}
    public $publicProperty;
    private $privateProperty;
}

class ChildClass extends AbstractClass {
    // Error
    private function publicMethod() {}

    // Allowed
    public function privateMethod() {}
    
    // Error
    private $publicProperty;
    
    // Allowed
    public $privateProperty;

}

trait MyTrait {
    public function publicMethod() {}
    private function privateMethod() {}
    public $publicProperty;
    private $privateProperty;
}

class MyClass {
    use MyTrait;

    // Allowed
    private function publicMethod() {}
    
    // Allowed
    public function privateMethod() {}
    
    // Error
    private $publicProperty;
    
    // Error
    public $privateProperty;

}


As to why the conflict resolution rules are different for properties and methods, this very long thread is informative. If I understand correctly, the summary is that properties are state, so if conflicts in a class’s state could occur, fatal errors are thrown so that developers can handle this. If one trait wants a property to be public and another wants it to be private, the latter might be surprised if that property were magically changed.
